# How does one identify compatible shower drain covers?

Tags: shower, drain

One of the several things that our contractor never completed on our project was the shower drain.  We've got this awesome hole in the shower floor right now:

[image]

Sorry, I know it looks nasty.

THe problem is that we don't know how to identify the brand, and therefore have no clue how to find a replacement drain cover.  There aren't even any screw holes there to attach anything!

It seems that aesthetically-speaking, the cover should go over the inner lip, but then there's very little support for someone to step on the cover without it deforming.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what we can do to find a compatible drain cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drain covers are specific to the tile drain manufacturer and can be difficult to find. Yours, however, looks to be of a common type and is very much like the middle one in this picture. I would take careful measurements and make a paper and crayon "rubbing" of your drain frame and go to the best plumbing supply shop in town (try a really good tile supply shop as well).

This is a website you might try: https://www.plumbingsupply.com/draincovers.html

[image]

It is odd that there are no screw holes in the drain scupper, the cut-outs in the tile frame are made to provide screw clearance. There is a chance that your tile guy tiled in a drain frame that was not the style meant for the actual drain assembly. If that is the case you may have to resort to a "snap-in" style retrofit cover. They never look as nice as the original but it's better than an open hole.

Comment: Jimmy, thank you so much.  I didn't know what to research, so I looked at "snap in", and sure enough, it looks like there *is* a matching part for my shower from Moen.  I just ordered it!